# Using the same styles for Jekyll Blog in subdomain of Node.js + nginx app

Tags: node.js, nginx, jekyll

I'm fairly new to working with nginx and server configs.

So my personal website is a Node app using nginx as a reverse proxy. I want to setup a Jekyll blog as a subdomain of my website in website.com/blog. I just got it working to serve a simple static html 'Hello World' page by adding an index.html file to /var/www/blog and modifying my sites-enabled/defaults to handle the /blog route by doing:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

So as for my next steps, I'm a little confused on what to do. For Jekyll, I will probably set up the git hooks like this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-jekyll-blogs-with-git) says but the issue is that I want to keep the page style the same as my website running on node.js.

I was wondering if there was a way - maybe in the config file or something - to set it so that Jekyll uses the same stylesheets as my node app so that the pages have a unified look to them?

My node app is the root directory of my server and the static page for the /blog endpoint is in the /var/www/blog/index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your setup, I guess that :

- **website.com** serves stylesheet at **website.com/style.css**,
- your jekyll blog is a new install, configured with **baseurl: /blog**

So when you're visiting **website.com/blog/**, your css is 404 because your blog page is looking for it at **website.com/blog/styles.css** and not at **website.com/style.css**.

In order to resolve this, in your blog _includes/head.html you can change :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "style.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Your css will now be requested as **website.com/style.css**.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!